# jQuery - dynamic table row deletion unsuccessful

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add and delete some rows in a table dynamically, and successful in adding dynamic rows. But I can't delete dynamically created rows where the rows created by html can be deleted using jQuery. I hear by enclose my codes

HTML:

```
<table id="customFields">
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="chk_nom" id="chk_nom"></td>
    <td><a class='rem' id="remScnt" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addCF">Add</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.rem').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
    $('.addCF').click(function(){
        $("#customFields").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="chk_nom" id="chk_nom"></td><td><a class="rem" id="remScnt" href="javascript:void(0);">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$('.rem').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

to

```
$('#customFields').on('click','.rem',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

so that the event handler also applies to the element you add to '#customFields' after you've set the event handling.

Comment: Thank you, i am again getting an error message in my firebug "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function". My jQuery version is 1.3.2

Comment: What error ? If it's unrelated, please open another question.

Comment: my error is on this line "$('#customFields').on('click','.rem',function()". And the error is "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function"

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ??? Always use a recent one. Pick at least the 1.10.

Comment: I am using 1.3.2. I will try with the latest. Thanks :)

Comment: This version was released in february 2009. That is a very long time ago in internet time. jQuery is designed to deal with browser differences, you can't expect a version made before today browsers to work well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(#customFields).on('click','.rem',function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Basically .click adds the handler when the page loads.

Because you are adding these items after page load the javascript has no idea they are there.

.on is a 'live' event meaning it will work at any time - even on newly added items!